# Facing Issue in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to laravel and ajax... i want to show the state of the selected country in dropdown list but when i select the country from the dropdown list it get data from the laravel perfectly and get it in ajax also.. but it is not able to append the data in html option tag.. for more details i am attaching the code of ajax also...`

```
$("#country").change(function(e){
  var countryid = $(this).val();
  console.log("Change Event Happpened on id : "+ countryid);
  $.ajax({
    type :"GET",
    url :"GetStates/"+countryid,
    success : function(statelist){
      $("#state").empty();
      $("#state").append('<option> Select State...</option>')
      $.each(statelist,function (statename,stateid) {
        **$("#state").append('<option>' + statename + ' </option>') // This line of code is not working**
        console.log("in each function");
      });
    }
  });
})
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `jQuery.each` function wrongly. [`jQuery.each` callback function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback) accepts two arguments:

```js
Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value )
```

So according to your (wrong) code:

```js
$.each(statelist,function (statename,stateid)
```

`statename` holds index of item and `stateid` receives `statelist` item, which clearly is against your idea.

Assuming that `statelist` has the following structure:

```js
statelist = [
  {
    statename: 'LA',
    stateid: 1
  }
]
```

callback function should look like the following:

```js
$.each(statelist,function (index, state) {
  $("#state").append(`<option value="${state.stateid}">${state.statename}</option>`)
});
```

You can use [javascript object destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring) to make this simpler:

```js
$.each(statelist,function (index, {stateid, statename}) {
  $("#state").append(`<option value="${stateid}">${statename}</option>`)
});
```

## Working code:

```js
const statelist = [{
    statename: "LA",
    stateid: 1
  },
  {
    statename: "MA",
    stateid: 2
  },
];

$("#state").empty();
$("#state").append("<option value=''>Please select a state...</option>");
$.each(statelist, (index, {
  statename,
  stateid
}) => {
  $("#state").append(`<option value="${stateid}">${statename}</option>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="state">
  <option>This will be removed</option>
</select>
```

Comment: dear same code is working fine when i use it in another file... and all the data is coming in console.log() i have check with it... issue is its just not appending in html code

Comment: What does statelist look like in success callback?

Comment: yes.. data is comning but the issue is $("#state").append('<option>' + statename + ' </option>') is not working ... i have tried the same code in another file its working fine... and same time i have checked for the jquery files which we have to add but then also its not working....